# Entity Framework Connection String Definition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I was just wondering that, what is **Entity Framework Connection String** really mean?
Like:

`metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=testSource;initial catalog=CatalogName;user id=sa;password=***********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework"`

I am aware of **provider=System.Data.SqlClient; provider connection string="data source=testSource; initial catalog=CatalogName; user id=sa; password=****

Can anyone tell me what does string `metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;`
 mean?

And, one more thing i need to confirm, if i want to edit in the Entity Connection String, can i do it?

Answer (score 5):

The metadata field is required in an EF connection string and specifies:

> A pipe-delimited list of directories, files, and resource locations in
>   which to look for model and mapping information.

(source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Or put in other words:

> The pointer to the metadata files (Conceptual Schema Definition Layer
>   [CSDL], Mapping Schema Layer [MSL], and Store Schema Definition Layer
>   [SSDL])

(source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-16.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Everything what you need, you have in manual:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=FpiOK3ZYdUD

Comment: This is actually a very useful page!