# Guide in determining the Database information from this connection string

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Somebody has sent me a visual studio web application solution that uses Entity Framework. I don't have much experience in Entity Framework and I'm trying to know what sort of datasource/database is he using in the application.

Here's the connection string:

```
<add name="newdatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=User;password=User;database=newdatabase&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I can understand that the database is hosted on his local server, but what other helpful information can i come up with concerning the datasource from this connection string?

Comment: see `database=newdatabase`

Comment: I can see `MySqlClient`, on `local` server with db `newdatabase` and username `User` with pass `User`

Comment: Thanks alot AmitKumar and PravinDeshmukh. What about the metadata section, what does it indicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134573/entity-framework-connection-string-definition